# IService extends IRepository correct?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, service-layer

It is correct to say that my IService has everything that IRepository has, and more some specific operations?

**Following is the code:**

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Add(T Entity);
    T Remove(T Entity);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
}

public interface IUserService
{

    //All operations IRepository
    User Add(User Entity);
    User Remove(User Entity);
    IQueryable<User> GetAll();

    //Others specific operations 
    bool Approve(User usr);
}
```

Note that all operations in `IRepository` are also `IService`.

**Is this correct?**

If so, it would be better to do something like this:

```
public interface IUserService : IRepository<User>
{
    bool Approve(User usr);
}
```

**Another option** would be:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    IRepository<User> Repository { get; }

    //All operations IRepository
    User Add(User Entity);
    User Remove(User Entity);
    IQueryable<User> GetAll();

    //Others specific operations 
    bool Approve(User usr);
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IRepository<User> _repository;
    public IRepository<User> Repository
    {
        get
        {
            return _repository;
        }
    }

    //Others specific operations 
    public bool Approve(User usr) { ... }
}
```

Note that I put the repository as a property, and in my service class'm exposing this property.

So if you need to add, remove or get some object in the repository I could access it via this property.

**What is your opinion?
Is correct in doing this?**

Comment: To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

    every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
    your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
    there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
    we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
    it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Comment: Maybe I'm not knowing how to ask the question. What I want to know is how do I expose the methods of my repository. If I expose them as property in my service, or create methods that access the methods of the repository.

Comment: @cadrell0: He provided 3 possible ways of doing something and asked which one of those he should use, not for subjective reasons but for objective ones.

Comment: The last line of the question is "What is your opinion?"  To me this falls under "I use _ for _, what do you use?".  I've recently gone through this at my job and it is a great question for an extended discussion.  It just seems to me that it is not a fit for SO's Q&A format.  There is no one correct answer to this question, and the selected answer will be based on personal preference.

Comment: I got it, actually in my context, to expose the repository as a property would be ideal.
If there is no one correct answer, and have no problems in exposing the repository, this would be what to do.

Answer (score 4):

You've probably already worked this out for yourself, but I will offer an opinion anyway.
Your second example:

```
public interface IUserService : IRepository<User>
{
    bool Approve(User usr);
}
```

is what you should use - it is nice and clean. Most of the stuff included in `IUserService` in your first example was totally redundant, the only thing `IUserService` actually adds is `bool Approve(User usr)`. You will also find that if you use your second example, when you add the `UserService` and get Visual Studio to automatically implement `IUserService` you end up with the following:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public bool Approve(User usr)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public User Add(User Entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public User Remove(User Entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IQueryable<User> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class User { }

public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Add(T Entity);
    T Remove(T Entity);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
}

public interface IUserService : IRepository<User>
{
    bool Approve(User usr);
}
```

As you can see, the types are all correctly populated for you, without having to do anything extra in `IUserService`.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking about exposing the repository as property; What do you think?